# Emulate highlight on view click

Tags: android, view, onclick

I have `ImageView` with some icon. Icon, for example, have size: 32 x 32 dip. ImageView have background:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/simple_button_focused_holo" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/simple_button_pressed_holo" />

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Then user click on icon, we can see some hightlight on click. All ok: work on 4 and 2 android version. But size 32 is so little for clicking. Therefore, I add hidden view and add onClick for this hidden view. This view have ~ 50dip and user can easy click on icon. But in this case, user don't see highlight on click. I cann't increase size source icon, because parent view have fix size and near icon also exists other views: textviews, progressbar (which not need response on click).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change the background color of the view when it receives a click? Use some transparent color so the user can still see the `Button`. Then you can setup a Thread to sleep for some certain amount of time, and then use `runOnUiThread()` and pass a Runnable that will set the background back to transparent?

Comment: ofcouse, I can this. But this is simulated way. At first want use some 'native' way.